# Differential Equation semantics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

is $y=ce^{2t}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \equiv y=\left(\frac{ce^{2t}-1}{2}\right)$?

I think they are equivalent because in the right equation $\left(\frac{ce^{2t}}{2}\right)$ ends up being another constant, say k. Therefore, I could rewrite the both equations like so:

$y=k-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \equiv y=k-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$

What do you think? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding or multiplying a constant are different things. Adding/subtracting  a free constant is ok. Multiplying is always not so, it carries through.

If   however you have $ dy/dx = k y, $ then $ y = c e ^{k y }$ the coefficient can be multiplied by an arbitrary constant.